# Number all occurring leaves in a tree from left to right in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

The function type would be `Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)`. I want to carry the count throughout the tree and number each occurring leaf accordingly.

So far I have tried this:

```
labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree (Leaf a) = Leaf (a,1)
labelTree (tr)     = labelTree' (tr) 0

labelTree' :: Tree a -> Int -> (Tree (a,Int))
labelTree' (Leaf a) n   = Leaf (a,(n+1))
labelTree' (Node l r) n = (labelTree' (r) (snd (labelTree' (l) n)))
```

The problem is I am not sure why it is giving me the type error for this expression: `labelTree' (Node l r) n = (labelTree' (r) (snd (labelTree' (l) n)))`

Please indicate where I went wrong!

Comment: Nice question! What did you try?

Comment: I just added the details. Please check!

Comment: You are trying to apply `snd` to a value of type `Tree (a, Int)`, not `(a, Int)`.

Comment: In addition, you are only returning the numbered right subtree from `labelTree`.

Comment: I see, how can i achieve that? i am interested in the second value of the tuple? So that i can pass it to right sub tree.  Do i need to work on the helper function which only returns a tuple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably need here is some sort of *accumulator*: a variable that you pass through the recursive calls, and each time you increment each time you "assign" the next id.

We thus define our function in terms of a helper function `go`. `go` will return a 2-tuple: the "labeled" tree, and the next id that we will "dispatch". This will later be used since we define a recursive call:

```
labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree = fst . go 0
    where go ...
```

So `go` has type `Int -> Tree a -> (Int, Tree (a, Int))`. In case we see a `Leaf`, we thus "dispatch" that id, and then return that leaf, together with `n + 1` as second part of the tuple, like:

```
go (Leaf x) n = (Leaf (x, n), n+1)
```

for a node, we will first dispatch ids to the left subtree, and then take the second item of that tuple as a start to dispatch elements to the right subtree, like:

```
go (Node l r) n0 = (Node ll lr, n2)
    where (ll, n1) = go l n0
          (lr, n2) = go r n1
```

We thus first call `go l n0` to label the left subtree, and obtain a 2-tuple `(ll, n1)` that contains `ll` the labeled left subtree, and `n1` the new number to dispatch later. We make a call to `go r n1` so we dispatch numbers to the right subtree starting with `n1`. Our `go` funcion thus returns a new `Node` with the labeled subtrees, and the new number to dispatch. This is important for the caller of this function.

So in full, we can label a tree with:

```
labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree = fst . go 0
    where go (Leaf x) n = (Leaf (x, n), n+1)
          go (Node l r) n0 = (Node ll lr, n2)
              where (ll, n1) = go l n0
                    (lr, n2) = go r n1
```

Answer (score 12):

I have the same idea in mind as chepner: to use State. However, you don't have to write the recursion yourself because this is a simple traversal of the tree! Instead, derive Traversable and Foldable for your tree (good ideas anyway), and then lean on them to do the recursion for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict as S
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
            deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree t = S.evalState (traverse applyLabel t) 0
  where applyLabel x = do
          n <- S.get
          S.modify' succ
          pure (x, n)

*Main> labelTree (Node (Node (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')) (Leaf 'c'))
Node (Node (Leaf ('a',0)) (Leaf ('b',1))) (Leaf ('c',2))
```

One nice feature of this implementation is that it will still work if you change the structure of your tree (e.g., to store data in the interior nodes). It is impossible to make mistakes like swapping the order of nodes, because you don't work at that level at all: Traversable handles it for you.

Comment: This is the same as `Data.Traversable.mapAccumL`, except that your version is a bit stricter. I'm not sure it's quite the right sort of stricter, though. Need to think that out. Regardless, I believe you should probably use `modify'` rather than `modify`.

Comment: "that it will still work if you change the structure of your tree" --> But then you depend on the right order of constructor arguments in the extended version of the tree.

Comment: @firefrorefiddle: yes, although (a) you can implement `Traversable` yourself, so you "decouple" the way one "traverses" over the tree, from this labeling. If you change your mind and implement the traversing in the reverse way, then this `labelTree` will change as well, and (b) I think amalloy is talking about changes like `Leaf a | Node [Tree a]` so we can make it more "robust" to some changes.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed. I am really not at all familiar with the stuff in Data.Traversable. You make a good point about my faux strictness. I've changed it to at least use `modify'`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `State` monad to keep track of the number to add to a node.

```
labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree l = evalState (labelTree' l) 0
    where labelTree' :: Tree a -> State Int (Tree (a, Int))
          labelTree' (Node l r) = Node <$> labelTree' l <*> labelTree' r
          labelTree' (Leaf a) = do n <- get
                                   put $ n + 1
                                   return $ Leaf (a, n)
```

`labelTree'` builds up a stateful computation which will number the leaves along an in-order traversal. `evalState` then runs the computation with an initial state of 0, so that leaves are numbered starting at 0.

The recursive case looks much like an ordinary tree function. Instead of simply applying `Node` to the results of each recursive call, you use the `Applicative` instance.

The base case numbers each `Leaf` using the current state and updates the state for the next leaf.

(Note that this is very similar to [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933298/1126841). Given that `State s a` is effectively a wrapper around functions of type `s -> (a, s)`, the type of `labelTree' :: Tree a -> State Int (Tree (a, Int), Int)` can be coaxed into the same type as `go`:

```
labelTree' :: Tree a -> State Int (Tree (a, Int)) 
            ~ Tree a -> Int -> (Tree (a, Int), Int)
go ::         Tree a -> Int -> (Tree (a, Int), Int)
```

)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the quick and dirty version:

```
{-# language DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Traversable (mapAccumL)

data Tree a
  = Leaf a
  | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Int)
labelTree = snd .
  mapAccumL (\k a -> (k+1, (a, k))) 1
```

Unfortunately, this is likely a bit too lazy to be very efficient in general. I'm still trying to work out how to hit the laziness sweet spot here.